# Why does Centauri keep wearing his disguise on the Starfighter base?

Tags: the-last-starfighter

In *The Last Starfighter*, an alien named Centauri disguises himself as a human and travels to Earth.  There he whisks away Alex, a young video game addict, to serve as a Starfighter, a spacecraft gunner.  Centauri's true identity is not revealed to Alex until, on the way to the Starfighter base, he is momentarily glimpsed without his disguise:

[image: Film still of Centauri without a disguise, showing his featureless black face. (From the original movie; I consider this fair use for the purposes of review.)]

For reasons I cannot fathom, Centauri continues to wear his human disguise after leaving Alex on the Starfighter base.  He doesn't need to conceal his identity from the other aliens on the base, because they already know who he is and that he is not a human.  And since his plan seems to have been simply to dump Alex on the base and collect his recruitment fee, it was not in his interest to remain recognizable to Alex.  In fact, it's only by coincidence that Alex manages to find Centauri again and demand to be taken home.  (And as a result, Centauri is forced to refund his fee.)

Out-of-universe, I'm sure Centauri continues to wear his disguise so that the audience can recognize him, and so that the actor, Robert Preston, can continue to emote freely.  (Non-disguised Centauri has a frighteningly featureless black face that would not lend itself well to Preston's "lovable conman" shtick.)  But is there some canon, *in-universe* explanation as to why Centauri retains his disguise?  By "canon" I mean that an explanation has been provided in the film's novelization, in the film's screenplay, in interviews or other documentary materials by the filmmakers, or (in case I overlooked it) in the film itself.

Comment: speculation: simple kindness. Centuari recognized that Alex was a) unnerved b) not quite in his right mind c) completely unfamiliar with aliens when his [Centauri's] form was revealed. It's possible he retained his human look simply as a grounding point for Alex: the one face Alex was at least nominally familiar with in this fish out of water adventure. Out of universe, it also makes the ending stinger reveal more effective

Comment: @NKCampbell: If he had any concern for Alex's mental state, he would have accompanied him after dropping him off. Instead, he just hands Alex over without explanation. He does crop up again once, very briefly, but then loses himself in the crowd once he's been paid. Alex spots him again only by accident.

Comment: I didn't say it was good speculation :D

Comment: Congrats on the first "real" The Last Starfighter question. (The other one is asking if TNG copied from it. )